Showing average value with relation (union and join)
I'm trying to show an average 'trophy' for some country that has more than 20 trophies - how do I do that?
This is my code
select 
    country, avg(trophy)
from 
    (select country, club from Tbl_Club1
     union all
     select country, club from Tbl_Club2) as country
join 
    Tbl_Trophy tr on country.club = tr.club
group by 
    country

And this is the result of this code:

Basically, I just want to show Italy and Spain only, because they have more than 20 average trophy

Add HAVING AVG(trophy) >20 after the group by perhaps

have a look into having clause

ok ill try it.. thanks for responding

@siggemannen it works.. thanks a lot

@ahmedabdelqader that's WMI syntax btw, it's not entirely sql server like

@siggemannen, Thanks, Right link as I cannot edit my pervious comment.

Please provide a [mre] with sample data and desired results as table markdown NOT images.
